# Why i can use locationInView but I can't use translationInVew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, I can use the `locationInView` method, but when I type the `traslationInView`, I can't use it and the system says: 
`No visible @interface for UIGestureRecognizer declares the selector 'translationInView'`.

All the format should be all right. How is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your reference is of type `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

As `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` so derived class members are not visible when you use super class refernce

Either type cast `UIGestureRecognizer` reference to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

Or simple replace `UIGestureRecognizer` with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in your method as

```
- (void)yourMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
}
```